# Is there a way to have more colors in Excel quick selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, templates

I have started using a custom template for Word and I was able to fit in the "Custom Colors" section by changing the .XML file inside the template. I tried to replicate this approach for an Excel template but this extra section is not showing up.

Word's "Custom Colors" Section:

[image: Word's "Custom Colors" Section]

Is there a way how to have more selectable colors in an Excel template?

Comment: This is not the fixed options...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "More Colors..." section, there are plenty of colors that you can choose from. This section provides different options to customize colors of elements like Hyperlink, text, background and you can also select custom colors according to your need.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware, but I always need to use the colors once for them to appear in the "Quick Selection". So when I am frequently in-between documents using 5-7 additional colors going back and forth copy-pasting Hex Values, it becomes a repetitive and annoying. In a Word document, I could just add additional 30ish colors and put it in a template, so every time I open a new document it's already there.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried the Create New Theme Colors option in Customize. I think will create different template, just name them and click save.

Comment: Yes, I am already using a custom theme, but when I do I can only have the "Theme Colors" and "Standard Colors" Selection. Not the extra "Custom Colors".

See the difference Here - https://imgur.com/a/gwX40EM

Comment: Yes, you are right. Are you using the updated version because I have seen somewhere that excel also provides the similar option.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Themes dropdown (mentioned above), you'll find a Customize option at the bottom of the list. Choosing this option will display a list of all the palette (theme) colors. Each color has a dropdown that you can use to replace the current color with another.

If that doesn't supply the color you want, find the RGB numbers for the color you want in the palette. To do so, find some content using the color you want to add to the palette. Open the font color dropdown and choose More Colors. Doing so will open a dialog with that color's RGB numbers. Write them down, because you will need them for the next step.

Return to the Themes Cutomize dialog, select the color you want to replace in the palette and click More. Then create a custom color using the RGB numbers you just reviewed. That color will replace the color you selected to replace.

Hope that's helpful!
Susan H.

Comment: Hi Susan, thank you for your reply, however that is not what I am having a problem with. 
See these images to compare, I know how to replace the theme colors, but don't know how to have an extra section in Excel. Works in Word. See here: https://imgur.com/a/gwX40EM

Comment: I've never seen that custom section before and without coding it from the bottom up, I know of no way to do that. Sorry I can't be more helpful. Susan H.